# CMD Args not recognized when starting container through Docker API

Tags: api, docker, containers

If i run a container via cli like this, works like a charm:

```
docker run --rm shashibanger/tsduck:1.0 tsp -I ip 1.1.1.1:50 -P until --seconds 30 -P analyze -w -o /1_1_1_1_50.txt -O drop
```

Output: *** Error: ip: address 1.1.1.1:50 is not multicast**  (Which is expected)

The problem appears when i try to do the exact same thing via Docker API. First, im creating the container with this json body:

```
{ 
  "Cmd": [
    "tsp",
    "-I ip 1.1.1.1:50 -P until --seconds 30 -P analyze -w -o /1_1_1_1_50.txt -O drop"
  ],
  "Image": "shashibanger/tsduck:1.0",
  "HostConfig":
  {
    "AutoRemove": true
  } 
}
```

Then, i start the container and recieve the following error:

```
tsp: unknown option -I
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: It's not a CMD problem, CMD surely ran `tsp -I .... ` but `tsp` threw the error that it couldn't recognize the option `-I`. Can you run the command outside docker and make sure if you get the same error or not.

Comment: Yes, works fine, also as i pointed, if i run the command with "docker run" works fine aswell.

Only fails when creating the container via API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `"Cmd":` array, you need to break each word into its own parameter

```js
"Cmd": [
  "tsp",
  "-I",
  "ip",
  "1.1.1.1:50",
  ...
]
```

As you've provided it, the equivalent `docker run` command would be more like

```sh
docker run --rm shashibanger/tsduck:1.0 tsp '-I ip 1.1.1.1:50 ...'
```

When you're running a command via the shell, it breaks each word into its own parameter.  When you use the Docker API (and most languages' "exec"-type functions) you need to do this yourself.

Comment: This works like a charm! I've tried before breaking each parameter like "-I ip 1.1.1.1:50", ... but didn't work.

Thanks